# GRASS R.viewshed.cva error -->Python (r.series) for folder

Tags: python, grass-gis, extensions

I am trying to use r.viewshed.cva to create viewsheds for over a hundred thousand of points. It actually works fine, I am getting over a million files but when it tries to combine all of them into one raster I am getting the [WinError206] saying that the file name would be too long .

So what I have now is an endless amount of single rasterfiles, which I am trying to combine by r.series. I have found this here

[image]

But which would the input directory?

Got them files in the hist/cellhd/cell_misc/cell/cats folder each.

Do I have to enter the full path to the "cell" folder?

If I am using the above code in simple editor with the cell directory I am getting the Syntaxerror for line 5.

Another problem might be that those files are not in TIFF format?

I have never used Python before.

Comment: I don't understand why you are getting a million (!) output files. If you feed a point vector to r.viewshed.cva then you should be get as output one single combined viewshed. (unless you used the `-k` flag to keep all interim rasters)

Comment: thats a good question. in the attribute table of the vector i got 53 FIDS/cats, the meta data tells me i got 120.000 Points. i have no idea, why it creates a file for every point in all of these 5 folders. -k is definitely off.
when im using r.viewshed.cva on just 150 points, it works rly well and deletes those files afterwards. But once im using more than 2000 it wont work nomore and im getting that WinError206 :/
Switching to Ubuntu probably wouldnt help my cause

Comment: What is your use case? It seems strange to create a viewshed for 100,000 points.